# Why would MySQL request a shared-lock after setting transaction level to READ UNCOMMITTED

Tags: mysql, deadlock, isolation-level, parallelism

Running a processing job in multiple parallel batches which basically reads big chunks of rows to update a few - it's OK here to use a lower transaction level since I know the relevant values won't be updated while this task is running so before calling each stored proc I run:

`set session transaction isolation level read uncommitted`

then call the stored proc which gets a subset of IDs to process. SQLFiddle of the overall operation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/192d62 (somewhat contrived but keeps to the structure of the original queries)

The reason I ask is the deadlocks continue to happen and looking into the Monitor output there's one thread requesting a shared lock while another holds an exclusive lock over the same space (or vice-versa) - shouldn't setting that transaction level prevent the need for a shared lock? Is there a reason to get a shared lock aside from `repeatable-read`?

Using InnoDB.

Relevant lock information from `show engine innodb status` (edited to match table name from SQLFiddle):

```
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 481628 page no 24944 n bits 112 index `PRIMARY` of table `events` trx id 27740892 lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
```

and

```
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 481628 page no 24944 n bits 112 index `PRIMARY` of table `events` trx id 27740898 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 481628 page no 25267 n bits 112 index `PRIMARY` of table `events` trx id 27740898 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
```

Note that query 1 and 2 in the SQLFiddle match the first and second entries in the engine output. The `PRIMARY` key is only over the `id` column (as can be seen in the Fiddle)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39975/discussion-between-jkavalik-and-michoel).

Answer (score 1):

"Read chunks, but only update a few of them"...

```
SELECT a chunk -- separate transaction, don't care about locking, etc
munch on that chunk to figure out the 'few' ids to update
BEGIN;
    SELECT ... WHERE id IN (list of the few) FOR UPDATE;
    minimal other work
    UPDATE them;
COMMIT;   -- plus checks for deadlocks, etc, and restart the code.
```

The idea is to pull as much time-consuming code *out of* the transaction as possible, thereby making the transaction faster, thereby minimizing the likelihood of conflict.  (No, it probably won't eliminate *all* deadlocks, but it should help.)

Another note:  If possible, go through the table in the same order in all threads.  Deadlocks happen when one thread plays with `id IN (1,2)` but another does `IN (2,1)`.  If both do `IN (1,2)`, then you get delays, not deadlocks.

Another tip:  Make the chunks smaller.